# props changes to undefined in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The below component of mine is very unstable.
"**this.state.list**" gets value from **this.props**. But immediately the state becomes "**undefined**".
Just not able to figure out why??? What is wrong with this code.

this.state.dropList

```
["2 mg/dL  -   Feb 21 2021 12:11:00", "5 mg/dL  -  Feb 21 2021 01:11:00"]
```

```
<ListItem dropList={this.state.dropList} />.  //call the component


export default class ListItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: []
        }
      }
    

     componentDidMount() {
        const {dropList} = this.props;
       this.setState({list: dropList})
    }


        render(){
            console.log("droplist inside:", this.state.list)
            return (
                <View>
            {
            this.state.list !== "" ?      
                <View>
                {      
                this.state.list.map((l,i) => (
                  <View key={l}>
                    <ListItem   
                    containerStyle={{padding: 4, backgroundColor:'#D3D3D3'}}
                    title={l}
                    accessible={true}
                    />
                    </View>
                ))             
              }
              </View>
              : null
           }
     </View>
            )
        }

}
```

Log

```
droplist inside: ["2 mg/dL  -   Feb 21 2021 12:11:00", "5 mg/dL  -  Feb 21 2021 01:11:00"]
droplist inside: undefined
droplist inside: undefined
droplist inside: undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're setting the `list` property of your state to the reference of `dropList`. Instead you want to do a copy by value of `dropList`.
Because `dropList` is an array of primitive types, then  you want to do `this.setState({list: [...dropList]})` instead of `this.setState({list: dropList})`. If `dropList` was another type of collection or structure, you would need to do a deep clone as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23536726/3185694).

Please try that and let me know if it helps :-)